# Given a tuple of $k$ distinct integers, is there a generator list in a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ that matches the tuple?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, chinese-remainder-theorem

Motivation: In $\langle\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z},\times\rangle,\ \langle 3\rangle = (3,2,6,4,5,1).$

> Given a $k-$tuple of distinct integers, $q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_k,$ (all
> nonzero) does $\exists$ integers $a,m,n$ with $n>\max\{ q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_k\},\ $ such that $a m^i \equiv q_{i}
>  \pmod n\ \forall\ i\in \{1,2,\ldots, k\}\ $
> [In other words, $q_i$ is the remainder when $am^i$ is divided by $n.]\ ?$

Maybe there is a counter-example like $(100,99,98, 3,2,1).$ But I doubt it. I imagine it is true and we can even take $a=1,$ for example. I think it could be true by Chinese remainder theorem and/or Fermat's Little theorem?

It should be true for $k=2,$ so maybe then we can use induction on $k$?

I think that without the "nonzero" and "all distinct" conditions, there would be easy counter-examples.

Edit: I think $n$ must be prime for this to work, right? Well, I think that if $n$ is prime then every number other than $0$ and $1$ "generates" all of $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\},$ although I don't recall the proof for this. But is it true that if n is not prime, then in $\langle\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\times\rangle,\ $ then for any $u,\ \langle u\rangle\ $ does not generate all of $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}\ ?$  Can someone link to proofs of these two theorems? I'm sure they are in some Elementary Number/Group Theory pdf. I also have the book, "Elementary Number Theory" by Springer, but I'm not sure if these theorems/proof are in there...

Comment: $n$ must be prime if you want to generate all the non-zero integers less than $n$. A tuple like $(2,3,4,8,16,32)$ doesn't have any obvious generator that I can find.

Comment: @CyclotomicField tuple $(2,3,4)$ is a counterexample since $3^2-2\cdot 4 = 1$, so there is no $n$ such that $q_2^2\equiv q_1q_3 \pmod n$, which would be necessary for $q_1 \equiv am$, $q_2\equiv am^2$ and $q_3 \equiv am^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want geometric sequence modulo some $n$, so $q_i^2 \equiv q_{i-1}q_{i+1}\pmod n$, i.e. $n\mid q_i^2-q_{i-1}q_{i+1}$, so to find counterexample you can take any triple $(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ such that $q_2^2-q_1q_3 = 1$, for example $q_1 = 1, q_3 = q_2^2-1$ with $q_2$ arbitrary.

In fact, take any three consecutive integers $x-1,x,x+1$, then $x^2\equiv (x-1)(x+1) \pmod n$ iff $n\mid 1$, so we have plenty of counterexamples.

For $k = 2$, the answer is almost trivial, take any prime $n$ greater tghan $q_1$ and $q_2$ and let $m \equiv q_2q_1^{-1}$, $a\equiv q_1m^{-1}$, where the inverse is modulo $n$. Or, slightly amusingly, take $n = q_1+q_2$, $m=-1$ and $a = q_2$. Then $q_1\equiv am\pmod n$, $q_2\equiv am^2\pmod n$.

---

For the questions in edit, this depends on what you mean by generate.
If by generate you mean you take the smallest ideal containing generator, then for a prime $p$, ring $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field by [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), since if $a\not\equiv 0 \pmod p$, $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime, so there are integers $x,y$ such that $ax+py = 1$ and therefore $ax \equiv 1 \pmod p$, so $x \equiv a^{-1} \pmod p$. The only ideals of a field are $(0)$ or the field itself, so all non-zero elements in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ generate the whole field.

If by generate you mean take the smallest multiplicative subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ containing generator, for non-zero $g$ in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ you want $\{g,g^2,\ldots,g^{p-1}\}$ to be all distinct, but this happens precisely when the order of $g$ in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ is $p-1$. This doesn't need to be the case for all non-trivial $g$, for example $4^2\equiv 1 \pmod 5$, so $\bar 4$ has order $2$ in $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$ and in general $\overline{p-1}$ has order $2$ in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ since $(p-1)^2 \equiv p^2-2p+1 \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Taking some non-zero $a$ and considering $\{ag,ag^2,\ldots, ag^{p-1}\}$ won't change anything since multiplication by $a$ is bijection on $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Of course, when $n$ is not prime, take a non-trivial divisor of $n$.

Comment: I get your first two paragraphs: nicely explained. Your third paragraph made me realise the question was more trivial than I intended; I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, I don't see that your update changes the answer, further restricting $n$ doesn't change the fact that there are always triples for which no $n$ exists, nor does it change the fact that in case of pair you can always take arbitrarily large prime. This is actually fine because editing question in a way that invalidates given answers is a bad practice.

Comment: My update doesn't change the answer to your first two paragraphs. However, your third paragraph, as it is written, implies that, given $k=2,\ q_1=6,\ q_2=10,\ $ we can take $a=1,\  m=2,\ n=2,$ which is a reductionist/trivial answer, because obviously $2^x\equiv 6\pmod 2,\ $ and $2^y\equiv 10\pmod 2\ $ for any integers $x,y.$ But then this is not answering the question I originally intended. My intention was not for it to be so trivial, even when to take $k=2,\ q_1=6,\ q_2=10.\ $

Comment: I want $q_1$ and $q_2$ to be remainders under division of $n,$ so I need $n> \max,\{q_1,q_2\}.$

Comment: There's a second part of that, which says that you can take arbitrarily large prime and invert $q_1$ since $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a field. For example, take $n = 11$, then $q_1^{-1}\equiv 2 \pmod {11}$, then $m\equiv 9\pmod {11}$ and $m^{-1} \equiv 5\pmod{11}$, so $a\equiv 8\pmod{11}$. @AdamRubinson

Comment: @AdamRubinson, in your comment you take $m=2$ but there is no reason for it. You can take bigger $m$. Say, $m=57$. The only problem with that is that I don't see that you can always find $a$ such that $ma\equiv q_1$ (anyway, your $a$ doesn't work, you should take $3$). Therefore, the second approach with taking $n$ prime is better. But, here's something funny. Take $n = q_1+q_2$, $m = -1$ and $a = q_2$. Then you have $q_1\equiv am\pmod n$ and $q_2\equiv am^2\pmod n$ and $n>\max\{q_1,q_2\}$.

Comment: In your answer you say, " let $n = |q_2-mq_1|$ for any $m$ such that $|q_2-mq_1| > 1$." This suggests that $m=2$ in my example, $q_1=6, q_2=10,$ should work, since $|10-(2)(6)| > 1$ is satisfied. Am I misunderstanding something, or do you need to amend your wording?

Comment: @AdamRubinson, I realized it doesn't quite work, but not for the reason you mention, it would work perfectly fine if we were give pair $(q_0,q_1)$ instead of $(q_1,q_2)$ because I can't see that for any $m$ we can find appropriate $a$. But, more importantly, you deliberately chose $m$ that gives trivial result, and I said that you can pick any $m$, so why didn't you try different $m$? Try $m=57$, you can even find appropriate $a$ in that case. Another important thing, you are completely ignoring the part that I keep repeating: pick $n$ any prime larger than $q$'s as a different approach.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the first part first. But I will try the other part when I get a minute

Comment: @AdamRubinson, I edited it because I can't guarantee that appropriate $a$ exists since I don't know if we can always solve equation $am\equiv q_1$. I didn't pay too much attention when I was writing it originally, because, honestly, I thought you understand that case from the way you wrote your question and just added it more as a comment. Current answer is more precise.

Comment: That's fair enough. I've always been a bit iffy with number theory and abstract algebra tbh. So sometimes I do miss the forest for the trees.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, well I can say the same, fair enough, although I really don't understand downvote when I completely answered your question, even the edited one.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer... (note that my question lost an upvote/got a downvote also)